# May I enter the UAE one day before visa expiry?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, uae, visa-expiration

I'm from India, living in the UAE. I'm going on vacation and returning to the UAE one day before my visa expires. Will I have a problem re-entering? I've heard that you have to re-enter at least one week before the visa expires.

Comment: @pnuts looks like a good answer to me (especially with the contact info).

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate what type of visa you have but, as you say that you live in UAE, and that can't be done on a visitor visa, and are Indian, most likely you have an employment permit which allowed entry, followed by a resident permit.

Despite news articles which suggest that visa renewal can be done while in UAE, other reports are contradictory.

During [live chat with Ministry of the Interior](https://www.moi.gov.ae/en/) agent Maha, and consistent with @pnuts feedback, you must contact Immigration before attempting to re-enter UAE:

Tel: +971 4 313 9999
Tel: +971 8 005 111
Email: amer@dnrd.ae